# How to mix up lines from two text files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three files to read in from the command line: The file to write to, the first file to read from, and second file to read from, respectively.

I'd like to write into my file the first line of the first file, the first line of the second file, second line of the first file, second line of the second file etc etc etc etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
import sys

writeTo, firstFile, secondFile = sys.argv[1: ]

text_file = open(writeTo, "w")

x = open(firstFile, "r")
y = open(secondFile, "r")

for linex in x:
    for liney in y:
        text_file.write(linex+liney)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
with open(firstFile) as f1, open(secondFile) as f2,\
                                             open(writeTo, 'w') as text_file:
    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
         text_file.write(line1 + line2)
```

If the files contain unequal amounts of lines then consider using `itertools.zip_longest`.